# Kohana 2.3 establish has one relationship between two tables with primary keys not named as "id"

Tags: php, kohana-orm, kohana-2

I have two tables. applicants and applicant_accounts.

```
applicants
 ->applicant_id   int(11) PK
 ->name           varchar(45)

applicant_accounts 
 ->account_id     int(11) PK
 ->applicant_id   int(11) 
 ->userName       varchar(45)
```

I've put this code code in my Applicants_Model it does'nt worked.

```
protected $has_one = array('applicant_account' => array('model' => 'Applicant_Account', 'foreign_key' => 'applicant_id'));
```

I tried to rename the primary keys into **"id"** and achieved my desired result by putting this code in my Applicants_Model.

```
protected $has_one = array('applicant_account');
```

And then accessed data from it by this

```
$applicant = ORM::factory('applicant', 1);
echo $applicant->name.' ----> '.$applicant->applicant_account->userName;
```

Please help me.I need to know how to have has_one relationship within two tables with primary keys not named as **"id"**

Applicant_Model

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Applicant_Model extends ORM {

    protected $has_one = array('applicant_account' => array('model' => 'Applicant', 'foreign_key' => 'applicant_id'));

    protected $primary_key = 'applicant_id';

}
```

Applicant_Account_Model

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Applicant_Account_Model extends ORM {

    protected $primary_key = 'account_id';

}
```

testing.php(for displaying purposes only)

```
$applicants = ORM::factory('applicant', 1);
echo $applicant->name.' | '.$applicant->applicant_account->userName.'<br>';
```

Comment: Oh. just a reminder. Im using kohana 2.3 and I saw my solution from kohana 3.2 so Im really not sure if it will work ahhaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my supervisor arrived here lately and he solved my problem. He changed the codes in the **Applicant_Model** into this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Applicant_Model extends ORM {

    protected $primary_key = 'applicant_id';
    protected $has_one = array('applicant_account');

    public function foreign_key() {

        $foreign_keys = array('applicant_account' => 'applicant_id');

        return $foreign_keys['applicant_account'];
    }

}
```

I dont really know what exactly he did but he said that he used a function inside the ORM.php and then used it to override the name of the foreign key. I hope this answer will help others.

Comment: Notice. This is for Kohana 2.x version and Im using 2.3